# Unable to fix my site after Commerce Promotion was enabled (no Commerce Cart enabled)

Tags: commerce, 9

I installed the sub module Commerce Promotion and my Drupal 9 site crashed with the following message, plus debugging code:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Class 'Drupal\commerce_cart\Event\CartEvents' not found in Drupal\commerce_promotion\EventSubscriber\CartEventSubscriber::getSubscribedEvents() (line 16 of /var/www/html/drupal9test/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/promotion/src/EventSubscriber/CartEventSubscriber.php).

Drupal\commerce_promotion\EventSubscriber\CartEventSubscriber::getSubscribedEvents() (Line: 37)
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RegisterEventSubscribersPass->process() (Line: 94)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile() (Line: 762)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 1293)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 898)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 471)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 705)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)
```

I was able to find in Issues for Drupal Commerce [the reason of my site crash](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3150268), I enabled sub module Commerce Promotion without enabling Commerce Cart sub module.

I added the commit at the end of that post but my site is not fixed. Any suggestion to bring back my site?

Comment: did you cleared cache? verify that class CartEvents exists?

Comment: Yes, cache is cleared. I don't know how to make a MariaDB search to check that CartEvents class exists. But I suspect it doesn't exist because of the debug message I shared: `Class 'Drupal\commerce_cart\Event\CartEvents' not found`

Comment: Fortunately it was a test site. I couldn't get it back, but it was mostly from not doing a backup earlier. Now I always make backup copies before installing modules, it is a must.